# Double count view in archive.php

Tags: posts, loop, count, archive-template, views

I'm having a hard time using [this snippet](http://wp-snippets.com/post-views-without-plugin/) I'm getting double views each time the post is queried.

This is in my functions.php file:

```
function getPostViews($postID){
  $count_key = 'post_views_count';
  $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
      delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
      add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
      return "0";
    }
    return $count;
  }
  function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
      if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
      }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
      }
  }

  // Remove issues with prefetching adding extra views
  remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

Then I places `setPostViews(get_the_ID());` into a template part that i loop in the archive.php like this:

```
  <?php 

  $term =   $wp_query->queried_object;
  $args=array(
    'post_type' => 'anuncio',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'ciudad',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $term->slug,
      ),
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key'   => '_adStatus',
        'value' => 'activo'
      )
    ),
  );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part('templates/ads/ad'); ?>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

This is my ad.php file:

```
<?php 
  $adID = $post->ID;
  $attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $adID );
  $size = "grid-cover";
  $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );
  $url = $image[0];
  setPostViews($adID);
?>
<a href="#" class="ad <?php echo $post->ID; ?> lazyBackground" data-background="<?php echo $url; ?>">
  <p class="h2 ad-title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
  <p><?php echo get_the_content(); ?></p>
  <form method="post" id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>clickCounter" class="hidden">
    <input type="submit" class="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
  </form>
</a>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    jQuery('.ad.<?php echo $post->ID; ?>').click(function() { 
      jQuery('#<?php echo $post->ID; ?>clickCounter').submit();
    });
    jQuery('#<?php echo $post->ID; ?>clickCounter').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: "action=adClickCounter&id="+<?php echo $post->ID?>,  
        success: function() {
          window.setTimeout(function(){
            window.open("<?php echo $reDirectUrl; ?>","_blank") 
          }, 50);
       }
     });
    });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You fire `setPostViews` twice in **ad.php**

1. via PHP `setPostViews($adID);`
2. via JS with your ajax function again.

Remove one, and you should be fine.